# Getting a crash inside SHBrowseForFolder()

Tags: winapi

I am getting a crash inside win32 fn:: SHBrowseForFolder().
The code is as follows:

```
            BROWSEINFO   bi = {0}; 
    TCHAR   szDisplayName[MAX_PATH]; 
    szDisplayName[0]    =   ' ';

    bi.hwndOwner        =   NULL; 
    bi.pidlRoot         =   NULL; 
    bi.pszDisplayName   =   szDisplayName; 
    bi.lpszTitle        =   _T("Please select a folder :"); 
    bi.ulFlags          =   BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS;
    bi.lParam           =   NULL; 
    bi.iImage           =   0;  

    LPITEMIDLIST   pidl   =   SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);//crashes
```

The crash comes only in some XP machines and doesn't come on vista machines.
Kindly suggest some solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling CoInitialize?

Answer (score 1):

What is the nature of the crash? Are we talking a recoverable error, or an unhandled chip exception such as access violation? The `ShBrowse` functions typically invoke explorer in some fashion - is it the explorer that is crashing? Perhaps it is caused by some kind of shell addin? Did you initialize COM first? Maybe some external factor such as anti-virus?

Comment: When I run it in debug mode it gives the following message :-
"ExeName.exe     has triggered a break point"

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that szDisplayName is not null terminated!